# What are the pros and cons of using a personal bank for investing vs something like e-Toro?

Tags: investing, banking, online-banking, ireland

I want to invest a small amount of money (about 1k to 5k) at the moment.

My personal bank ([AIB](https://aib.ie/our-products/investments)) offers some investment products. I suppose my main goal is to avoid inflation and big fees. At the moment my savings account has only tiny interest and the yearly fees on my chequing account mean that I actually lose money every year by having my money in a bank!

What are the pros and cons of using my personal bank service vs just investing on an internet platform like [eToro](https://stocks.etoro.com/en/commission-free/v1?utm_medium=SEM&utm_source=21732&utm_content=0&utm_serial=391158912%7CAG_1201766845056283%7CKW_etoro%7CMT_e&utm_campaign=391158912%7CAG_1201766845056283%7CKW_etoro%7CMT_e&utm_term=&msclkid=b232f168c507145c03e7919908ddcd8c)?

Comment: I advised my son to invest in *funds* at an **Established** *Low Cost Broker*. and would definitely advise him **against** purchasing individual stocks from an upstart fintech app.  Being in the US, and because I invest there, it was "mutual funds" at Vanguard; there must be similar brokerages with offices in Ireland.

Comment: And definitely not your bank; they're definitely too expensive.

Comment: @RonJohn That definitely depends on the bank.

Comment: Cons: Risk. Pros: Reward. You will practically\* never lose (nominal) money in a savings account. But the stock market could crash in half tomorrow, are you okay with that possibility?

Comment: If you are buying in euros, the interest rates converting to $ with etoro are atrocious and likewise $ to € when withdrawing.

Comment: @ob318 why would someone in Ireland convert to $?

Comment: @RonJohn when I used etoro a year ago upon making a purchase on the platform (depositing) it was in dollars - an international purchase. It's an American platform.  Likewise on withdrawal.

Comment: @ob318 good to know.  That would make a good "Con" answer.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, when trading over eToro you are not buying actual shares but CFDs (contract for difference, a derivative). This adds counterparty risk: if eToro (or another party actually selling the CFDs) defaults you will have to wait for liquidation and will only get a small fraction of your money back. In contrast, if you buy actual shares or fund units, these are kept separate from your broker. Should your broker default, you can transfer your shares to another broker.